# How to find $F'(x)$ where $F(x)=\int_{-x}^{x}\frac{1-e^{-xy}}{y}dy?$

Tags: real-analysis

> How to find $F'(x)$ where $$F(x)=\int_{-x}^{x}\frac{1-e^{-xy}}{y}dy,x>0?$$

I've tried with fundamental theorem of integral calculus but it didn't help.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiation_under_the_integral_sign...

Comment: NOTE : please consider that fundamental theorem of Integral calculus is not for limits which are varying both sides....

Comment: The integration interval contains zero, so this is an improper integral. Does it *even* converge?

Comment: Got something from the answer below? You have been remarkably silent about it...

Answer (score 1):

A direct approach is to use the change of variable $y=t/x$ and to split the resulting integral. This yields
$$
F(x)=\int_{-x^2}^{x^2}\frac{1-\mathrm e^{-t}}{t}\mathrm dt=\int_0^{x^2}\frac{1-\mathrm e^{-t}}{t}\mathrm dt-\int_0^{-x^2}\frac{1-\mathrm e^{-t}}{t}\mathrm dt.
$$
From there, the value of $F'(x)$ should be clear.

If ever the varying bounds not being $x$ are a problem, use the change of variable $t=s^2$ in the first integral and $t=-s^2$ in the second one. This yields
$$
F(x)=2\int_0^{x}\frac{1-\mathrm e^{-s^2}}{s}\mathrm ds-2\int_0^{x}\frac{1-\mathrm e^{s^2}}{s}\mathrm ds=2\int_0^{x}\frac{\mathrm e^{s^2}-\mathrm e^{-s^2}}{s}\mathrm ds.
$$

Comment: I think even for this we have to use above formula i have mentioned as limits are not just $x$ but $x^2$... please tel me if i am missing something...

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik Maybe you are. See expanded version.

Comment: now it does makes sense to me.. Than you :)